# R: Tree graph with vertex information in plot

Tags: r, plot, tree, igraph

I'm trying to plot my data, which has a hierarchical structure, and I would like to visualize it using a tree structure. This is my attempt thus far:

```
library(igraph)

df <- data.frame("node_name"=c("root", "root0", "root1", "root00", "root01", "root10", "root11"),
                 "parent"=c("root", "root", "root", "root0", "root0", "root1", "root1"),
                 "incident"=c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                 "rating"=c(1, 0.97, 1.02, 0.95, 0.99, 0.99, 1.09))

g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(d=df[, c("node_name", "parent")],
  vertices=df[, c("node_name", "incident", "rating")])

pdf()
plot(g, layout=layout_as_tree(g, flip.y=FALSE))
dev.off()
```

This is what I get out:
[image: tree]

I see no way of adding the vertix information to the plot. I can access it using e.g. `V(g)$rating`, but I can't seem to add it to the plot.
Are there any other packages in `R` that I can use to visualize my data and include the `incident` and `rating` information in each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to add the info into ***edges*** rather than ***nodes***, and below might help

```
g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(
    d = df[, c("node_name", "parent")]
) %>%
    set_edge_attr(name = "label", value = with(
        df,
        paste0("incident:", incident, "\n", "rating:", rating)
    ))


plot(g, layout = layout_as_tree(g, flip.y = FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: fantastic! can you show me how I do this without using the %>%, I don't use `dplyr`. Is it also any way of making the tree symmetrical around root node?

Comment: @Helen You can replace `%>%` by `|>`, which is supported by base R

Comment: @Helen moving the positions of nodes to your desired places is possible, but you may need extra manual work to design the coordinates in the layout. I personally would like to have it as it is :)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to make it run, I get `object 'rating' not found`. Sure the code above is reproducible? Apologies if this is on me...
The reason I would like them to be symmetrical, is because if you add another layer, the edges seem to cross each other...

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I can't get |> to work...

Comment: Got this to work:

`g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(
    d = df[, c("node_name", "parent")]
) ;
g <- 
  set_edge_attr(g, name = "label", value = with(df, paste0("incident:", incident, "\n", "rating:", rating)))
`